# Why isn't this basic "R.useWith" working properly?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm fairly new to Ramda, and still trying to wrap my head around certain functions. Currently, I'm struggling a bit with `R.useWith`.

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
let myArray = [
  {
    a: 'wat', 
    b: 'foo'
  },
  {
    a: 'something',
    b: 'something_else'
  },
  {
    a: 'booyah',
    b: 'duh'
  } 
];
```

And I want to set a property of `foo` to equal `bar` on EACH object. I know there are several ways to do this, and I'm only using this as a contrived example while I try to learn this function. One way would to do this:

```
let setFooToBar = R.assoc('foo')('bar');
let mapMyArray = R.map( R.__, myArray );
```

So at this point, I have a function `setFooToBar` that expects an object, and will set property `foo` to `bar`, and I have a function `mapMyArray` that expects a function, and will map each `object` from `myArray` to that function. So, as expected, this works:

`mapMyArray( setFooToBar )`

Now, what I don't understand, is why THIS approach isn't working the way I'd expect it to:

```
let callFirstWithSecond = ( arg1, arg2 ) => arg1( arg2 );

R.useWith( 
  callFirstWithSecond,
  [
    R.map( R.__ ),
    R.assoc('foo')
  ]
)( myArray, 'bar' )
```

I would expect this to return the same thing as the previous approach, a new array of objects, each with a new property of `foo` set to `bar`. However, it is actually returning a new function. I can't figure out where I'm missing arguments.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your understanding of `useWith`.

The problem is the use of the placeholder, `R.__` in

```
 R.map( R.__ )
```

Using the placeholder as the last argument does not make sense.  It is used as a signal that "the argument that goes here will be supplied later."  Since Ramda functions are already curried, using it without anything to follow is a no-op.

```
let someFunc = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => 'whatever';
someFunc(argA, __, __, argD) ~>
    (p2, p3) => someFunc(argA, p2, p3, argD)

// but
someFunc(argA, argB, __, __) ~>
    (p3, p4) => someFunc(argA, argB, p3, p4) ~==
    someFunc(argA, argB)
```

You can get the behavior you want by replacing `R.map( R.__ )` with `R.flip( R.map )`.

You can see this in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?code=let%20myArray%20%3D%20[%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%20%27wat%27%2C%20b%3A%20%27foo%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%20%27something%27%2C%20b%3A%20%27something_else%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%20%27booyah%27%2C%20b%3A%20%27duh%27%7D%0A]%3B%0A%0Alet%20callFirstWithSecond%20%3D%20%28%20arg1%2C%20arg2%20%29%20%3D%3E%20arg1%28%20arg2%20%29%3B%0A%0AR.useWith%28%20%0A%20%20callFirstWithSecond%2C%0A%20%20[%0A%20%20%20%20R.flip%28%20R.map%20%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.assoc%28%27foo%27%29%0A%20%20]%0A%29%28%20myArray%2C%20%27bar%27%20%29)**.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks so much, Scott! That makes total sense... what a silly mistake.

Comment: This suggests that [cyclical placeholders](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def/issues/73) are intuitive. ;)